# Where Do I Declare Unity Container?

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm just getting started with Unity, and I'm having trouble finding any advice about where to declare my UnityContainer object.  Most of the examples that I've seen consist of just a single method where the UnityContainer object is declared at the top, then its mappings are defined, then a few object types are resolved.  But how do you handle the container when you need to access it in several places throughout the program?  For example, the user clicks on a button which opens a new window and that window needs a controller, which itself needs to resolve several services?  I also want some of the services that Unity manages to be singletons, so wouldn't that mean that I'd have to have only a single instance of my UnityContainer throughout my program to manage those singletons?

My first thought is to have my main Program class have a static UnityContainer property or expose some sort of UnityContainerFactory class which manages a singleton UnityContainer instance, but both of those methods seem bad because they create a global property which a lot of things are dependent on.

What's the accepted way of doing this?

Comment: what kind of application are you building? A WPF application? or a Web Site? Can you share some code that is relevant to the problem? specially the code that needs to locate the service?

Comment: A WinForms application.  For example, the user clicks a button, and the event handler/command behind the button opens a new window and needs to pass some services into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the other answer, you should compose the entire object graph in the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

Don't declare the container as a static field since this would encourage developers to use it as a service locator which [is an anti-pattern](http://yacoubsoftware.blogspot.com/2015/10/object-composability-another-reason-why.html).

How to solve your problem?

Use [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Here is an example for your special WinForms case:

In your Program.Main method, create the container, register the service (the dependency that you need to use from the other window) and then resolve the main form and run it like this:

```
UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

container.RegisterType<IService, Service>();

Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.Run(container.Resolve<MainForm>());
```

In the MainForm, declare a dependency on a `Func<SecondForm>` where `SecondForm` is the form that you need to create from the main form when the button is clicked. Consider the following code inside your main form file:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private readonly Func<SecondForm> m_SecondFormFactory;

    public MainForm(Func<SecondForm> second_form_factory)
    {
        m_SecondFormFactory = second_form_factory;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SecondForm second_form = m_SecondFormFactory();

        second_form.Show();
    }
}
```

Please note that `Func<SecondForm>` acts as some kind of factory. I use it in this case because unity has a [feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660854(v=pandp.20).aspx) to support late construction of dependencies via `Func`.

The `SecondForm` has a dependency on `IService` like this:

```
public partial class SecondForm : Form
{
    private readonly IService m_Service;

    public SecondForm(IService service)
    {
        m_Service = sevice;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //Use service here
}
```

You can now use `IService` from the second form.

Answer (score 2):

Using Seemann words:

> *As close as possible to the application's entry point.*

Give a look at http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/ from the great Seemann.

I think that is totally acceptable for the main container to be a static field that get disposed together with your application, just remember to don't tie your classes to your container.
Get noticed of the so called "Service Locator" (again from Seemann: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/)

Where to declare it really depends on the application, I'd go for the startup class of an owin application or the Main method of a console/WPF app.

Comment: Actually, having the container inside a static field would encourage the developers to use the container as a service locator. So I would say that we should not have such static field. If we need to use a container, we should create it, register types with it, resolve the root object, and then run the application.

Comment: [Here is another reason](http://yacoubsoftware.blogspot.com/2015/10/object-composability-another-reason-why.html) why you shouldn't use the container as a service locator.

Comment: As my application is running, I need access to the UnityContainer when I'm responding to a UI event that requires me to get a new controller or service.  I'm trying to avoid doing the whole static field/service locator thing, but I can't figure out a good way to get access to my UnityContainer without having some sort of global reference to it.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding how Unity works regarding singletons.  Don't I need to use the same UnityContainer object throughout my application if it has singletons registered with it?